# Java: efficiently store boolean[32]?

Tags: java, performance

In Java, I would like to store (>10'000) arrays of boolean values (boolean[]) with length 32 to the disk and read them again later on for further computation and comparison.

Since a single array will have a length of 32, I wonder whether it makes sense to store it as an integer value to speed up the reading and writing (on a 32 bit machine). Would you suggest using BitSet and then convert to int? Or even forget about int and use bytes?

Comment: What is more important to you: efficient storage, or efficient (i.e. fast) read/write?

Comment: I think fast read/write is much more important in this application

Comment: Do you want to just write and read all arrays once, or do you need random access to specific arrays?

Comment: Yes, arrays are all read at once. No random access necessary

Comment: Would it be reasonable to see this as a 2-dimensional boolean array, i.e. boolean[10000][32]?

Comment: So far I use a 2-dim boolean array. However, the 2-dim array does not really represent a matrix. One boolean array used here can be thought of being a feature vector (for pattern recognition purposes); the second dimension is just used for convenience

Comment: what kind of comparison do you do? It may be possible to speed up that as well using bit operations.

Comment: at the end I would like to sum up how many values are equal, i.e. doing an AND

Comment: In that case I'd certainly go for a special representation of the vector, using ints internally. That way, you can AND all the bits at once and then count the bits in the result, e.g. using a lookup table per byte or a switch/case per nibble.

Comment: How about just `int[10000] array`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For binary storage, use `int` and a `DataOutputStream` (`DataInputStream` for reading).

I think boolean arrays are stored as byte or int arrays internally in Java, so you may want to consider avoiding the overhead and keeping the int encoding all the time, i.e. not use boolean[] at all.

Instead, have something like

```
public class BooleanArray32 {
  private int values;

  public boolean get(int pos) {
    return (values & (1 << pos)) != 0;
  }

  public void set(int pos, boolean value) {
     int mask = 1 << pos;
     values = (values & ~mask) | (value ? mask : 0);
  }

  public void write(DataOutputStream dos) throws IOException {
    dos.writeInt(values);
  }

  public void read(DataInputStream dis) throws IOException {
    values = dis.readInt();
  }

  public int compare(BooleanArray32 b2) {
     return countBits(b2.values & values);
  }

  // From http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html
  // Disclaimer: I did not fully double check whether this works for Java's signed ints
  public static int countBits(int v) {
    v = v - ((v >>> 1) & 0x55555555);                    // reuse input as temporary
    v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >>> 2) & 0x33333333);     // temp
    return ((v + (v >>> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >>> 24; 
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, now, this is definitely better than BitSet for the OP's requisites.

Comment: Makes completely sense! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fixed an error in set and moved the static helpers to the bottom. You probably want to double-check the bit counts in the bitsInNibble helper. Let us know if everything works as expected for your task :)

Comment: Update2: changed bitcount to method described here: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: Update2 looks great! Looks very neat (and the link is very interesting)! Thanks!

Comment: Following this back a few more steps closer to the root source, here is Ian Ashdown's post to *comp.graphics.algorithms* from 15 February 1996: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.graphics.algorithms/ZKSegl2sr4c/QYTwoPSx30MJ

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I am under the strong impression that any compression you are going to make to pack your boolean values will **increase** the read and write time.</strike>  (my mistake, I was clearly missing my medication). You will rather gain in terms of storage involved.

BitSet is a sensible choice on your business logic side. It internally stores a long, which you could convert to an int. However, since BitSet is prude enough not to show you its privates, you need to get each bit index in sequence. This means that I guess there is no real advantage converting to an int rather than just using bytes directly.

The roll-your-own solution of Stefan Haustein (extended as necessary to mimic BitSet) is therefore preferable for your storage requirement, since you do not incur any unnecessary overhead.

Comment: The first sentence is certainly not true: Storage is organized in bytes or larger units, and several orders of magnitude slower than memory access and simple calculations.

Comment: You are correct about the organization and the memory access ratio, however you also need to consider caches. I will fix my answer to account for that.

Comment: I don't see how caches are involved here. Note that this is not really about compression, just about storing one bit as a single bit instead of a byte or more.